# Search for Filename and Parent Folder Using Regex - Python

Tags: python, regex, directory, path, filenames

I am trying to confirm the filename and parent folder for a file using the regex library and without having to explicitly list the file path, but encountering issues.  I want to print out the name of the file and also the parent folder to the file, here is my script:

```
import re
import glob
from pathlib import Path

files = [f for f in glob.glob('*.tif') if re.search('((?i)\/Image_Names\/.*_dsm.*\.tif)', f)]

for filename in files:
    print(files)  # list the files
    print(Path().resolve().parts[-2])  # list the parent folder from where the .tif file resides
```

I am able to list the parent folder to the .tif using the Path function, but cannot list the filename itself.  I need to be able to print the filename (_dsm.tif) and parent folder (Image_Names) explicitly via regex, any assistance is most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
files = [re.search(r'(?i)(Image_Names)/(.*_dsm.*\.tif)', f).groups() for f in glob.glob('*.tif') if re.search('(?i)Image_Names/.*_dsm.*\.tif', f)]
```

The output will be like `[('Image_Names', 'xxxx_dsm.tif'), ('Image_Names', 'bbbb_dsm_blah.tif')]`.